# How to pass variable into route in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

**routes/web.php**

```php
$urls = \App\Myurls::all();

foreach($urls as $url){
  Route::get($url->en,  function() {
    session(['lang'=> 'en']);
    return view( 'en.'.$url->view );
  });
}
```

**Error :  Undefined variable: url** ( in *return view()* line)

How to pass `$url` variable into Route::get function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be use `function() use ($url)`

```
$urls = \App\Myurls::all();

foreach($urls as $url){
  Route::get($url->en,  function() use ($url) {
    session(['lang'=> 'en']);
    return view( 'en.'.$url->view );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `use` the variable in the [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php):

```
Route::get($url->en,  function() use ($url) {
  session(['lang'=> 'en']);
  return view( 'en.'.$url->view );
});
```